# Trojanagent in swap_1

Tags: swap

First I'll just say that I'm a rookie Linux user. Still getting used to the transition ya know. Main reason I switched is because of malware and storage space. Anyway i was just exploring the /Dev dir because I'm trying to figure out how I can get rid of the LVM Ubuntu VG_swap1 because I don't need it. Well I attempted to open swap_1 in /dev and immediately realized my mistake so ctrl>c, and was left with computer lingo but I started scrolling through it and found thousands of Trojan.agent droppers, etc. What's that about??

```
/dev/ubuntu-vg$ ls -l swap_1 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Oct  6 11:18 swap_1 -> ../dm-1
```

swap_1 is the suspected /dev. Here is a small piece of what i found. I admit, most of it is gibberish. I'm learning.

```
Win.Trojan.Fosniw-2369Win.Trojan.Downloader-10031Win.Trojan.Agent-506148
Win.Trojan.561779-1 Win.Trojan.5476770-1Win.Trojan.Agent-506149Win.Adware.Gamevance-7381Win.Adware.Gamevance-7382Win.Adware.Gamevance-7383
Win.Trojan.331339-2�W�^�W�^he^>���&_�?/րe^`B�^Win.Adware.Gamevance-7384Win.Trojan.6040813-1Win.Trojan.Injecter-116
Win.Worm.Agent-506150Win.Trojan.Agent-506151Win.Trojan.Agent-506152
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include some `ls -l ` examples of the suspected files.

Comment: Please include output of `swapon -s` and `free -m` as well. My suggestion would be to leave the swap space alone, especially as you're a new user.

Comment: Do you have some kind of antivirus software installed?

Comment: I do. ClamAV. I was thinking that maybe I was picking up on it's database but I don't know how that would be possible considering the data originated from swap_1. And what I listed above is just a small percentage, and I even hit ctrl>c so there would've  been more data.

Comment: I don't use it, but my unsupported guess is that what you are seeing is a database from the av program.

Comment: Organic Marble Yeah I think you're probably right. There's nothing out of place or missing. Performance is good other than the ridiculous amount of RAM being used.